# PHP - Not Sending Emails with Header Information

Tags: php, email, header

I am having a problem sending emails when I add header information.
However when I just remove the header parameter it works. What is wrong? Is it the code? Or some setting I need to change on the web server admin panel to say "Allow-Headers" or something?
I am trying to send to hotmail in case this has any relavance in determining the problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Below Doesn't Send Email:

```
<?php

    $to      = 'iputmyrealemailhere@hotmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com';

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Below Sends Email:

```
<?php

    $to = 'iputmyrealemailhere@hotmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com';

    mail($to, $subject, $message);

?>
```

Comment: Try sending to Gmail and look it up in Spam. Hotmail has a tendency to discard emails that do not respect the RFC standards.

Comment: Try adding `\n` in the end of `$headers`, but it's just a guess.

Comment: @PetrR. Actually he should add \r\n but the server should also add it if it's not present.

Comment: Adding `\r\n` to both `subject` and `headers` should theoretically work. However, you should consider adding a `From:...` in there (as part of your headers). Most email services/clients will most probably consider it as Spam, without it.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the php error log? If you capture the return value when sending (`$result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);`) is it true or false?

Comment: @tntu **Should** and **Will** are 2 different `animals` altogether. It's very unlikely, what with today's stricter rules and checking.

Comment: seriously, you should use a library like phpMailer for sending mail via php. The built-in `mail()` function has a *lot* of shortcomings.

Comment: @Spudley: `mail()` is fine if you just want to send a simple mail. And third party scripts like `PHPMailer` do not warrant success either. In order to debug `mail()` calls, the very first thing you need to do is check the return value of `mail()`.

Answer (score 1):

I use these headers in my php mailing function and it works well. **Note**: I also use a third party mail-routing service to avoid having my mails marked as coming from a spammy IP. You might want to look into that also.

```
$headers = 'From: '.$from.'@foo.net' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$from.'@foo.net' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

I also use the optional fifth parameter to `mail()` to set the envelope address, e.g.:

```
$parameters = '-f '.$from.'@foo.net';
```

so the final call is:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, $parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the "FROM:" from the headers list .. it prevents it in some hosts .But the real question then will be how ca I change the sent from email address to a specific email that I want